# Java JCheckBox ArrayList help needed

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, arraylist, deserialization

I'm new to Java and struggling with something which I'm sure must have a simple answer but I can't seem to find it.
I have an array of checkbox objects defined as:

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkBoxList
```

A JPanel is created with a grid layout and the checkboxes are added to the JPanel and the ArrayList:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    JCheckBox c = new JCheckBox();
    c.setSelected(false);
    checkBoxList.add(c);
    mainPanel.add(c);
 }
```

Yes, there are 256 checkboxes! The panel is added to a JFrame and eventually the GUI is displayed. The user can select any combination of the 256 checkboxes.

My class implements Serializable and this ArrayList of checkboxes can be saved and restored using 'Save' and 'Load' GUI buttons. My code to load the saved object is as below:

```
public class LoadListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

        try {

            // Prompt the user for a load file
            JFileChooser fileLoad = new JFileChooser();
            fileLoad.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);

            // Create a object/file input stream linking to the selected file 
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileLoad.getSelectedFile()));

            // Read the checkBox array list
            checkBoxList = (ArrayList<JCheckBox>) is.readObject();              
            is.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

On loading the ArrayList object, the values of the checkboxes are correctly populated, however I want to update the checkboxes on the GUI to reflect this.
Is there an easy way to do this? I assumed as the array of checkboxes had the correct values that I could just repaint the panel / frame but this doesn't work. I'd like to understand why - does my loaded array of checkbox objects no longer reflect the checkbox objects on the GUI? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A bit of clarification is still required. You want to reflect it on the panel ?

Comment: You don't need to implement Serializable, ArrayList already implements Serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that of References. The ArrayList object being read stores only references of JCheckBoxes that were in the memory at the time of saving. So instead of writing the whole ArrayList object to the file, just save the states of the JCheckBoxes(true or false) and on reading them back, set the states manually as:

```
//write the states
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("path"));
Iterator<JCheckBox> i=checkBoxList.getIterator();
while(i.hasNext())
{
JCheckBox box=i.next();
oos.writeBoolean(box.isSelected());
}
oos.close();
```

If you already have the JCheckBoxes instantiated and putted nicely in your arraylist Do this While reading the saved file:

```
 // Create a object/file input stream linking to the selected file 
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileLoad.getSelectedFile()));

for(int i=0;i<256;++i)
checkBoxList.get(i).setSelected(is.readBoolean());
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, although I made a couple of subtle changes - I did the save and load in an ArrayList 'for' loop to save the need for an iterator i.e. `for (JCheckBox c : checkBoxList) {
     os.writeBoolean(c.isSelected());
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If this helps in your question - here's the ready-made version of the code:

```
 /**
 * Restore a melody from the file
 */
private class RestoreMelodiListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        boolean[] checkboxState = null;
        try {
            JFileChooser fin = new JFileChooser();
            fin.showOpenDialog(theFrame);

            File selectedFile = fin.getSelectedFile();

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(selectedFile));
            checkboxState = (boolean[]) ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (JCheckBox check : checkboxList) {
            check.setSelected(check.isSelected());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            JCheckBox check = checkboxList.get(i);
            check.setSelected(checkboxState != null && checkboxState[i]);
        }
        sequencer.stop();
        buildTrackAndStart();
    }
}

/**
 * Save ringtone to file
 */
private class SaveMelodiListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        boolean[] checkboxState = new boolean[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            JCheckBox check = checkboxList.get(i);
            if (check.isSelected()) {
                checkboxState[i] = true;
            }
        }
        try {
            JFileChooser fin = new JFileChooser();
            fin.showOpenDialog(theFrame);

            File selectedFile = fin.getSelectedFile();

            if (selectedFile != null) {
                FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
                os.writeObject(checkboxState);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gitst of this code: https://gist.github.com/romanitalian/d6df0a0dab4e001d9386c47889dcea11